# C# GPA calculator

Tags: c#

Below is the code of GPA calculator in c#. I am feeling like the code that I write and format are quite long. I used the function DisplayOne(); DisplayTwo(): etc to disable and enable the text boxes according to radio button. Instead of using those function and writing all lines of code "txtCCode1.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode2.Enabled = false;s
        txtCCode3.Enabled = false;" etc I like to know is there any other option to write the program without using ".Enable = true/false" or using ".Enable = true/false" but for one time only. Not to writing for until DisplayOne(); to DisplaySix();.

```
    public double gradePoint1, gradePoint2, gradePoint3, gradePoint4, gradePoint5, gradePoint6;
    public double courseGP1, courseGP2, courseGP3, courseGP4, courseGP5, courseGP6;
    int credHour1 = 0, credHour2 = 0, credHour3 = 0, credHour4 = 0, credHour5 = 0, credHour6 = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // make the display bigger
        this.Font = new Font("Arial", 15);
    }

    private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // to disable certain text boxes according to the number of courses taken
        if (rad1.Checked)
            DisplayOne();
        else if (rad2.Checked)
            DisplayTwo();
        else if (rad3.Checked)
            DisplayThree();
        else if (rad4.Checked)
            DisplayFour();
        else if (rad5.Checked)
            DisplayFive();
        else
            DisplaySix();
        InitializeLabels();
    }

    private void InitializeLabels()
    {
        // initialize all Credit Hours labels
        lblCH1.Text = "0";
        lblCH2.Text = "0";
        lblCH3.Text = "0";
        lblCH4.Text = "0";
        lblCH5.Text = "0";
        lblCH6.Text = "0";
    }

    private void DisplayOne()
    {
        txtCCode1.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode2.Enabled = false;
        txtCCode3.Enabled = false;
        txtCCode4.Enabled = false;
        txtCCode5.Enabled = false;
        txtCCode6.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade1.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade2.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade3.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade4.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade5.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade6.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void DisplayTwo()
    {
        txtCCode1.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode2.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode3.Enabled = false;
        txtCCode4.Enabled = false;
        txtCCode5.Enabled = false;
        txtCCode6.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade1.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade2.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade3.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade4.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade5.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade6.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void DisplayThree()
    {
        txtCCode1.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode2.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode3.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode4.Enabled = false;
        txtCCode5.Enabled = false;
        txtCCode6.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade1.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade2.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade3.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade4.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade5.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade6.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void DisplayFour()
    {
        txtCCode1.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode2.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode3.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode4.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode5.Enabled = false;
        txtCCode6.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade1.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade2.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade3.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade4.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade5.Enabled = false;
        txtGrade6.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void DisplayFive()
    {
        txtCCode1.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode2.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode3.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode4.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode5.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode6.Hide();
        txtGrade1.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade2.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade3.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade4.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade5.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade6.Hide();
        lblCH6.Hide();
    }

    private void DisplaySix()
    {
        txtCCode1.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode2.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode3.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode4.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode5.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode6.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade1.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade2.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade3.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade4.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade5.Enabled = true;
        txtGrade6.Enabled = true;
        txtCCode6.Show();
        txtGrade6.Show();
        lblCH6.Show();
    }

    private void txtCCode1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // to find the right most character from the course code = CREDIT HOURS
        string courseCode = txtCCode1.Text;
        string rightMost = courseCode.Right(1);
        lblCH1.Text = rightMost;
        credHour1 = Convert.ToInt32(lblCH1.Text);
    }

    private void txtCCode2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string courseCode = txtCCode2.Text;
        string rightMost = courseCode.Right(1);
        lblCH2.Text = rightMost;
        credHour2 = Convert.ToInt32(lblCH2.Text);
    }

    private void txtCCode3_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string courseCode = txtCCode3.Text;
        string rightMost = courseCode.Right(1);
        lblCH3.Text = rightMost;
        credHour3 = Convert.ToInt32(lblCH3.Text);
    }

    private void txtCCode4_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string courseCode = txtCCode4.Text;
        string rightMost = courseCode.Right(1);
        lblCH4.Text = rightMost;
        credHour4 = Convert.ToInt32(lblCH4.Text);
    }

    private void txtCCode5_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string courseCode = txtCCode5.Text;
        string rightMost = courseCode.Right(1);
        lblCH5.Text = rightMost;
        credHour5 = Convert.ToInt32(lblCH5.Text);
    }

    private void txtCCode6_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string courseCode = txtCCode6.Text;
        string rightMost = courseCode.Right(1);
        lblCH6.Text = rightMost;
        credHour6 = Convert.ToInt32(lblCH6.Text);
    }

    private void txtGrade1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gradePoint1 = FindGradePoint(txtGrade1.Text);
    }

    private void txtGrade2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gradePoint2 = FindGradePoint(txtGrade2.Text);
    }

    private void txtGrade3_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gradePoint3 = FindGradePoint(txtGrade3.Text);
    }

    private void txtGrade4_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gradePoint4 = FindGradePoint(txtGrade4.Text);
    }

    private void txtGrade5_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gradePoint5 = FindGradePoint(txtGrade5.Text);
    }

    private void txtGrade6_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gradePoint6 = FindGradePoint(txtGrade6.Text);
    }

    private double FindGradePoint(string grade)
    {
        double gradePt=0;
        switch (grade)
        {
            case "A+":
            case "A":
                gradePt = 4.00;
                break;
            case "A-":
                gradePt = 3.75;
                break;
            case "B+":
                gradePt = 3.5;
                break;
            case "B":
                gradePt = 3.0;
                break;
            case "B-":
                gradePt = 2.75;
                break;
            case "C+":
                gradePt = 2.5;
                break;
            case "C":
                gradePt = 2.0;
                break;
            case "C-":
                gradePt = 1.75;
                break;
            case "D+":
                gradePt = 1.5;
                break;
            case "D":
                gradePt = 1.0;
                break;
            case "E":
                gradePt = 0.5;
                break;
            case "F":
                gradePt = 0.0;
                break;
            default:
                DialogResult x = new DialogResult();
                x = MessageBox.Show("Error in Alphabet grade", "Error");
                if (x == DialogResult.OK)
                    txtGrade1.Focus();
                break;
        }
        return gradePt;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int totalCredHours = 0;
        CalcTotalCredHours(credHour1, credHour2, credHour3, credHour4, credHour5, credHour6, ref totalCredHours);
        courseGP1 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour1, gradePoint1);
        courseGP2 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour2, gradePoint2);
        courseGP3 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour3, gradePoint3);
        courseGP4 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour4, gradePoint4);
        courseGP5 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour5, gradePoint5);
        courseGP6 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour6, gradePoint6);
        double totalCGP = CalcTotalCGP(courseGP1, courseGP2, courseGP3, courseGP4, courseGP5, courseGP6);
        double gpa = CalcGPA(totalCGP, totalCredHours);
        lblGPA.Text = gpa.ToString("N");
    }

    private double CalcCourseGradePoint(int ch, double gp)
    {
        double cgp = ch * gp;
        return cgp;
    }

    private double CalcGPA(double tcgp, int tch)
    {
        double gpa = tcgp / tch;
        return gpa;
    }

    private double CalcTotalCGP(double cgp1, double cgp2, double cgp3, double cgp4, double cgp5, double cgp6)
    {
        double totCGP = cgp1 + cgp2 + cgp3 + cgp4 + cgp5 + cgp6;
        return totCGP;
    }

    private void CalcTotalCredHours(int ch1, int ch2, int ch3, int ch4, int ch5, int ch6, ref int tch)
    {
        tch = ch1 + ch2 + ch3 + ch4 + ch5 + ch6;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text.Right(4).ToLower();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your question is better suited towards [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), although read their guidelines before posting

Answer (score 1):

To start with you should add a parameter to these methods; DisplayOne(), DisplayTwo() etc

```
private void DisplayNumbers(int number)
{
    txtCCode1.Enabled = (number <= 1);
    txtCCode2.Enabled = (number <= 2);
    txtCCode3.Enabled = (number <= 3);
    txtCCode4.Enabled = (number <= 4);
    txtCCode5.Enabled = (number <= 5);
    txtCCode6.Enabled = (number <= 6);
    txtGrade1.Enabled = (number <= 1);
    // ....
}
```

If you want to take it further you could create a class which holds references to the controls for each number.

```
class Number {
    public int NumberValue { get; set; }
    public RadioButton ShowVisible { get; set; }
    public TextBox CodeTextBox { get; set; }
    public TextBox GradeTextBox { get;set; }

    public void SetVisible()
    {
         this.CodeTextBox.Visible = this.ShowVisible.Checked;
         this.GradeTextBox.Visible = this.ShowVisible.Checked;
    }
}
```

Then in your button click:

```
for(int number = 0; number < this.Numbers.Length; number ++)
    this.Numbers[number].SetVisible();
```

Numbers will need to be an array of Number objects, which you will need to create.